# Using Pagination with Specifications

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I'm completly new with pagination and don't know anything. Never worked with it. Someone told me it's easy and good to use Specifications to use Pagination and stuff. Now i sucessfully implemented my specification, but I have no idea how pagination works and how i will get it to my frontend.

Normally I got a list which displaying everything in the database. But when I use Pagination object i need to have a Page so I changed the list to Page.

What I tried until now:

SearchController:

```
public class SucheController {
    @Autowired
    private TelefonbuchRepository telefonbuchRepository;
    private Page<Telefonbuch> eintraege;
    private Telefonbuch telefonbuch = new Telefonbuch();

       public void search(String vorname, String nachname, String telefonnummer, String handynummer) {  
            if (!vorname.isEmpty()) {   
                eintraege = telefonbuchRepository.findAll(TelefonbuchSpecifications.hasVorname(vorname), PageRequest.of(0, 5));
            }
```

I don't find any tutorial for exactly that so i just tried to pass my specification and an Pagination element. When I search the error is:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [id] not found on type [org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl]
```

How to do it correctly? Do you know any tutorials or websites for this? I don't even know if i can show Page objects on frontend. I'm using JSF with xhtml files. If you need more information tell me.

[image]

Edit:
suche.xhtml on request:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="telefonbuch" value="#{sucheController.eintraege}" stickyHeader="true" resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true" style="margin-bottom:20px" paginator="true" rows="10" emptyMessage="Keine Telefonbucheinträge vorhanden" selection="#{telefonbuchList.selectedEntry}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{telefonbuch.id}"
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30">
```

I see the telefonbuch.id now at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You properly implemented specifications, by making sure your repository extends `JpaSpecificationExecutor`, and by calling the [`findAll(Specification, Pageable)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-) method

However, this method returns a `Page<TelefonBuch>` object, which you've assigned to a  field called `eintraege`. From the exception you posted, it appears that you're trying to directly obtain a property called `id` on top of your `eintraege`, so I assume you have something like `${eintraege.id}` within your JSF code, and that won't  work, because it  has no `id` property.

What you probably wanted to do is to loop over all objects within `eintraege`, and to show the ID of each one of them. That means you probably need to do something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="telefonbuch" items="#{eintraege.content}">
    <h:outputText  value="#{telefonbuch.id}" />
</c:forEach>
```

What happens here is that we loop over [`eintraege.getContent()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html#getContent--), which returns a collection that can be iterated over. Then you should assign each object to a variable (eg. `telefonbuch`), and then you can call properties like `#{telefonbuch.id}`.

Comment: Wow I can't believe that it is so easy. Just changed it back to List and added a .getContent to telefonbuchRepository.findAll(TelefonbuchSpecifications.hasVorname(vorname), PageRequest.of(0, 5)) and it works! Thank you! Do you know an tutorial or can you tell me how to pair this backend pagination now with my frontend primefaces?